# .gif image doesn't moves on adding it to the JTabbed pane

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, animated-gif

I have a JFrame. In that i have two containers i.e two JPanel. one Panel holds a image. other holds a JButton. Then these two are added to JTabbedPane.

My problem is on using a .gif image the image becomes static as any other normal .jpg image. Can anyone help me with some more ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class ICLOUD implements ActionListener {

private BufferedImage bg;
JButton b1;
private Object frame1;
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();

  JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    public ICLOUD() {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("anigif.gif");
        bg = ImageIO.read(url);

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }


        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 300);
        }
    };



    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 15, 15));
    buttons.setOpaque(false);



    ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon(ICLOUD.class.getResource("hi.jpg"));

    b1=new JButton("Hello");

    buttons.add(b1);





    tabPanel.add(buttons);


    JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabPane.addTab(null,icon5, tabPanel);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("I-CLOUD");
    b1.setVisible(true);
    frame.setContentPane(tabPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}






public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
            ICLOUD r=new ICLOUD();
        }






@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



 }
```

Comment: This is a limitation of both `ImageIO` and the way that `JPanel` is painted.  If this is important to you, consider using a `JLabel` and loading the image via `ImageIcon`.  Can it be done using your method, yes, but you will be responsible for loading the frames and setting up the animation thread...

Comment: @MadProgrammer- Can you suggest any other method?

Comment: Apart from using `ImageIcon`?  Read each image from the `GIF` using `ImageIO` sub image capabilities and animate it yourself...

Answer (score 13):

Let me demonstrate the hole you are digging yourself into

You could do...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("anigif.gif"));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
add(label);
```

Or you could do...

[image: AnimatedGif]

Now, this is woefully inadequate and is designed for example purposes only.  It does not support disposal methods or optimized Gifs...so you can begin to imagine the amount of additional work that would be required to make this work...lots...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class PlayAnimatedGif {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PlayAnimatedGif();
    }

    public PlayAnimatedGif() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private AnimatedGif ag;

        public TestPane() {
            URL url = getClass().getResource("/playanimatedgif/ajax-loader.gif");
            try {
                ag = new AnimatedGif(this, url);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            ag.play();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            BufferedImage currentFrame = ag.getCurrentFrame();
            if (currentFrame != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - currentFrame.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - currentFrame.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(currentFrame, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static class AnimatedGif {

        public enum DisposalMethod {
            RESTORE_TO_BACKGROUND,
            RESTORE_TO_PREVIOUS,
            DO_NOT_DISPOSE,
            UNSPECIFIED;

            public static DisposalMethod find(String text) {

                DisposalMethod dm = UNSPECIFIED;

                switch (text) {
                    case "restoreToBackgroundColor":
                        dm = RESTORE_TO_BACKGROUND;
                        break;
                }

                return dm;

            }
        }

        private List<ImageFrame> frames;
        private int frame;
        private Timer playTimer;

        private JComponent player;

        protected AnimatedGif(JComponent value) {
            this.player = value;
            frames = new ArrayList<>(25);
            playTimer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    frame++;
                    if (frame >= frames.size()) {
                        frame = 0;
                    }
                    player.repaint();
                    playTimer.setDelay(frames.get(0).getGraphicControlExtension().getDelayTime());
                }
            });
        }

        public AnimatedGif(JComponent player, URL url) throws IOException {
            this(player);
            try (InputStream is = url.openStream(); ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is)) {
                Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
                if (!readers.hasNext()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("no image reader found");
                }
                ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
                reader.setInput(stream);            // don't omit this line!
                int n = reader.getNumImages(true);  // don't use false!
                System.out.println("numImages = " + n);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
                    ImageFrame imageFrame = new ImageFrame(image);

                    IIOMetadata imd = reader.getImageMetadata(i);
                    Node tree = imd.getAsTree("javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0");
                    NodeList children = tree.getChildNodes();

                    for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node nodeItem = children.item(j);
                        NamedNodeMap attr = nodeItem.getAttributes();
                        switch (nodeItem.getNodeName()) {
                            case "ImageDescriptor":
                                ImageDescriptor id = new ImageDescriptor(
                                        getIntValue(attr.getNamedItem("imageLeftPosition")),
                                        getIntValue(attr.getNamedItem("imageTopPosition")),
                                        getIntValue(attr.getNamedItem("imageWidth")),
                                        getIntValue(attr.getNamedItem("imageHeight")),
                                        getBooleanValue(attr.getNamedItem("interlaceFlag")));
                                imageFrame.setImageDescriptor(id);
                                break;
                            case "GraphicControlExtension":
                                GraphicControlExtension gc = new GraphicControlExtension(
                                        DisposalMethod.find(getNodeValue(attr.getNamedItem("disposalMethod"))),
                                        getBooleanValue(attr.getNamedItem("userInputFlag")),
                                        getBooleanValue(attr.getNamedItem("transparentColorFlag")),
                                        getIntValue(attr.getNamedItem("delayTime")) * 10,
                                        getIntValue(attr.getNamedItem("transparentColorIndex")));
                                imageFrame.setGraphicControlExtension(gc);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    frames.add(imageFrame);
                }
            } finally {
            }
        }

        public BufferedImage getCurrentFrame() {
            // If this was a optimised GIF, we would need to be 
            // merging frames together to produce the current frame
            // This would then need to be reset each time we cycle...
            return frames.isEmpty() ? null : frames.get(frame).getImage();
        }

        public void play() {
            if (!frames.isEmpty()) {
                frame = 0;
                playTimer.setDelay(frames.get(0).getGraphicControlExtension().getDelayTime());
                playTimer.start();
                player.repaint();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            playTimer.stop();
        }

        protected String getNodeValue(Node node) {
            return node == null ? null : node.getNodeValue();
        }

        protected int getIntValue(Node node) {
            return node == null ? 0 : getIntValue(node.getNodeValue());
        }

        protected boolean getBooleanValue(Node node) {
            return node == null ? false : getBooleanValue(node.getNodeValue());
        }

        protected int getIntValue(String value) {
            return value == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(value);
        }

        protected boolean getBooleanValue(String value) {
            return value == null ? false : Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
        }

        public class ImageFrame {

            private BufferedImage image;
            private ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor;
            private GraphicControlExtension graphicControlExtension;

            public ImageFrame(BufferedImage image) {
                this.image = image;
            }

            protected void setImageDescriptor(ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor) {
                this.imageDescriptor = imageDescriptor;
            }

            protected void setGraphicControlExtension(GraphicControlExtension graphicControlExtension) {
                this.graphicControlExtension = graphicControlExtension;
            }

            public GraphicControlExtension getGraphicControlExtension() {
                return graphicControlExtension;
            }

            public BufferedImage getImage() {
                return image;
            }

            public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {
                return imageDescriptor;
            }

        }

        public class GraphicControlExtension {

            private DisposalMethod disposalMethod;
            private boolean userInputFlag;
            private boolean transparentColorFlag;
            private int delayTime;
            private int transparentColorIndex;

            public GraphicControlExtension(DisposalMethod disposalMethod, boolean userInputFlag, boolean transparentColorFlag, int delayTime, int transparentColorIndex) {
                this.disposalMethod = disposalMethod;
                this.userInputFlag = userInputFlag;
                this.transparentColorFlag = transparentColorFlag;
                this.delayTime = delayTime;
                this.transparentColorIndex = transparentColorIndex;
            }

            public int getDelayTime() {
                return delayTime;
            }

            public DisposalMethod getDisposalMethod() {
                return disposalMethod;
            }

            public int getTransparentColorIndex() {
                return transparentColorIndex;
            }

            public boolean isTransparentColorFlag() {
                return transparentColorFlag;
            }

            public boolean isUserInputFlag() {
                return userInputFlag;
            }

        }

        public class ImageDescriptor {

            private int imageLeftPosition;
            private int imageTopPosition;
            private int imageHeight;
            private int imageWeight;
            private boolean interlaced;

            public ImageDescriptor(int imageLeftPosition, int imageTopPosition, int imageHeight, int imageWeight, boolean interlaced) {
                this.imageLeftPosition = imageLeftPosition;
                this.imageTopPosition = imageTopPosition;
                this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
                this.imageWeight = imageWeight;
                this.interlaced = interlaced;
            }

            public int getImageHeight() {
                return imageHeight;
            }

            public int getImageLeftPosition() {
                return imageLeftPosition;
            }

            public int getImageTopPosition() {
                return imageTopPosition;
            }

            public int getImageWeight() {
                return imageWeight;
            }

            public boolean isInterlaced() {
                return interlaced;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

If you want to fill it out, take a look at the [GIF Specifications](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt)...