# How to draw a gif animation in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, animation, graphics

I have some gif animated images (see sample image below)
and when I draw them with the graphics object, I am getting only the first image,
I know I can do this with JLabel (from other stackoverflow answers)
but I want to do that with the graphics object,
can anyone please tell me
an **easy** way how to draw the whole animation?[image: gif animation]

Comment: Sure, take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188940/gif-image-doesnt-moves-on-adding-it-to-the-jtabbed-pane/22190844#22190844) and take your pick of how much work you'd like to do ;) - Just remember, this is an EXAMPLE, it's not a complete solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer does it really have to be so much code for one gif?

Comment: Actually, you'd probably need more, this is essentially what's going on in the background with `JLabel` and `ImageIcon`, it's just nicely hidden away for you.  This is also why the `ImageObserver` and `ImageProducer` interfaces are so important

Comment: See also [Show an animated BG in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/418556).

Comment: A simplified example can be found here : https://tutoref.com/how-to-display-an-animated-gif-in-java-swing/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> "please tell me an **easy** way how to draw the whole animation?!"

It may have to to do with how you're reading in the image. If you use ImageIO.read, it won't work. If you read it as an `ImageIcon` it seems to work

**ImageIcon.getImage()**

```
Image icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSnus.gif")).getImage();
...
g.drawImage(icon, 20, 20, this);
```

[image]

**Image with ImageIO**

```
Image icon = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSnus.gif"));
...
g.drawImage(icon, 20, 20, this);
```

[image]

Comment: Or, if you're really crazy (or mad), you can roll your own, like the example linked in the comments to OQ :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer maybe you should change you SN to CrazyProgrammer :P

Comment: I'll just be LazyProgrammer :)

Comment: @peeskillet thanks, it works but i have a funny situation, when I'm drawing the image like your example, the other image i load from my computer is also drawing, but when i comment it out the first one isn't drawing,**: (**

Comment: @java-love Wait, so it's _not_ one gif file? You want to animate multiple files into one animated image?

Comment: no i have the same file on my computer, and when i copy your code into the same class i have 2, *1+1 = 2*,**:)**

Comment: @java-love Can you post a simple runnable example replicating this. I may not be understanding what's happening.

Comment: where can i post code?

Comment: @java-love click the edit link under your post. And _below_ your current post description, just write **EDIT** and post your code below it.

Comment: Let’s make it simple, how do I load the image from my computer and not from the internet?

Comment: @java-love OH ok, `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/image.gif")).getImage();` where `resources` is in your `src`.

Comment: thanks for saving me from MadProgrammer's answer,***: )***