# How to download an animated gif picture with httpClient in java

Tags: java, image, httpclient, gif

I need download an animated gif picture from Internet with httpClient.
I used this method.

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientUtils.getResponse(httpGet);
InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedImage sourceImg = ImageIO.read(is);
ImageIO.write(sourceImg, "gif", file);
```

But the picture is static.

for example:

I want:[image]

Actually:[image]

The actual picture is the first of the animated gif.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with ImageIO.write(). Look at this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240328/how-to-draw-a-gif-animation-in-java and post any results.

Comment: No need for ImageIO, just write out the raw bytes you get from the response to a file.

Comment: Gimby, please post an answer. that is the correct response.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I don't post answers which are with 100% certainty to exist as a question and answer already. I also don't post answers to question which are very likely to stem from copy/paste code.

Comment: @Gimby thank for your advice.It works.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Gimby said,he's right,no need for ImageIO!

```
InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new file(path),bytes);
```

Thanks.