# Extract metadata from image file using Java

Tags: java, image

I want to read properties like created_date, modified_date, creator, etc... in Java, of the below image file formats:

- GIF file
- JPEG
- TIFF
- CDR

I have used javax.imageio but I didn't find the solution.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could take look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188940/gif-image-doesnt-moves-on-adding-it-to-the-jtabbed-pane/22190844#22190844) which uses the meta-data from a GIF to render the animation contained within

Comment: Have a look here http://www.exiv2.org

Answer (score 3):

you can use [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) like ..

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imageFile);
```

Comment: i have tried this but i wont be able to get metadata like created date,modified date,creator etc

Comment: @prasanna, you can get all those values and more using the library. Check [here](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/GettingStarted#query-the-raw-value-of-a-specific-tag) for information on how to access a specific tag's value.

Comment: @DrewNoakes but is there a generic approach? Especially for image dimension the only way I found with your library so far is to deal with specific implementation, while I would just like to have something like `Image#getWidth`. It is kind of a pain to have to know that for `jpeg` that is value `3` and for `png` is `1`. Maybe a new question?

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish not in the library. It would be a useful addition, though tricky to get right. This issue tracks the idea, so please share your thoughts there https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/10

Answer (score 1):

Try [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/). It's very mature and well-suported metadata extraction libraty.